# Webapp - Dynamic Ajax for multiple forms

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

i am building a webapp to keep track of some customers details and other various information

what im chasing is a simple ajax function that i can reuse multiple times in the same page the send data to another page from various forms like a new customer form and say new lead form or do i need to create different ajax functions for each

i have this demo code from my login page however its for a specific form i would like for it to be able to just be given a varibale of the form name and submit all the fields in that form to another page is this possible

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('#form').on('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var wa_username = $('#wa_username').val();
        var wa_password = $('#wa_password').val();
        var datas='wa_username='+wa_username+'&wa_password='+wa_password;     
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/limitless/functions.php',
                dataType: 'json',
               data: datas,
                           success: function(data) {
                               if(data.status == '1')
                                {
                                    document.location.href = '/limitless/dashboard';
                                } 
                               if(data.status == '2')
                                {
                                    $('#info').addClass('alert alert-danger no-border').html(data.message);
                                }                               
                            }              
            })
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.serialize()` method on a form creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation.

```
 $(this).serialize() //this produces wa_username=test&wa_password=123
```

you could split this like below or instead of creating the datas just call the line above

```
$('#form').on('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();         
        postForm($(this).serialize());
});

function postForm(formData){
  $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/limitless/functions.php',
                dataType: 'json',
               data: formData,
                           success: function(data) {
                               if(data.status == '1')
                                {
                                    document.location.href = '/limitless/dashboard';
                                } 
                               if(data.status == '2')
                                {
                                    $('#info').addClass('alert alert-danger no-border').html(data.message);
                                }                               
                            }              
            })
}
```

Comment: hey mate im trying to implement this into my code any chance on showing me a form and the code working above in like a jsfiddle if you have time

Comment: i basically just need to see a form with multiple input fields and the ajax script i am completely new to ajax